# Eigenvalues of sum of Hermitian matrices with certain constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices and $\{\lambda_{A1},\ldots,\lambda_{An}\}$ and $\{\lambda_{B1},\ldots,\lambda_{Bn}\}$ represent their eigenvalues, respectively. If $A+B = \Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matix with diagonal elements $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ and $\lambda_{Bn}=0$, can we find $\lambda_{An}$?

Comment: Do you mean that $\lambda_{Bj} = 0$ for $j = 1,\dots,n$, or do you specifically mean that $\lambda_{Bn} = 0$ (and that the other eigenvalues are unknown)? Are these eigenvalues ordered in any particular way?

Comment: One or some eigenvalues of $B$ are zero, not all of them. I assume all eigenvalues are non-negative. Thus, $\lambda_{Bn}$ is the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: For $n=2$ you can do it. Assume all entires are real. Order all eigenvalues in ascending order. Since $B$ has rank 1, then you have the sum of the symmetric matrix and rank 1 matrix. Thus the theory says $\lambda_i(\Lambda)=\lambda_i(A) + u_i \cdot trace (B)$, where $u_i \in (0,1)$ and $u_1+u_2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem (or as an instance of Weyl's inequality) that
$$
\lambda_{min}(\Lambda) = \lambda_{min}(A + B) \geq \lambda_{min}(A) + \lambda_{min}(B) = \lambda_{min}(A)
$$
On the other hand, by another instance of [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory), we can get
$$
\lambda_{min}(\Lambda) = \lambda_{min}(A + B) \leq \lambda_{max}(A) + \lambda_{min}(B) = \lambda_{max}(A)
$$
We can't say anything more substantial than that.  Both of these inequalities are sharp, and equality is attained with diagonal matrices $A,B$.

Another theorem of Weyl's states that adding a positive semi-definite (PSD) matrix can only increase the eigenvalues. (One definition of PSD is that it has all non-negative eigenvalues). Thus, if $B$ is PSD,
$$
\lambda_{k}(\Lambda) \geq \lambda_{k}(A)
$$
for $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, and vice versa if $A$ is also PSD.